# Antivirus in Macbook

Tags: anti-virus

Do we need to install antivirus in OS X? I'm using macbook Pro 13" currently. Which antivirus is recommended (and free)? Any other better way to protect information in OS X?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. I think you mean OS X, not iOS? MacBooks run OS X. iOS is the OS on iPhones, iPads, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean OS X, not iOS? MacBooks run OS X. iOS is the OS on iPhones, iPads, etc.

Some good, free antivirus options for OS X are [Avast](https://www.avast.com/en-in/free-mac-security) and [AVG.](http://www.avg.com/in-en/avg-antivirus-for-mac)

You're definitely safer if you use them. There *are* viruses out there for OS X. That said, it's not as needed as it is on Windows. I personally don't use any antivirus on OS X, because I feel that it slows down the system a little bit. I feel the risk is rather small, so I am willing to take it.

It comes down to how careful you want to be. If you don't mind your system slowing down a little bit, and want to minimize the risk of viruses as much as possible, then get antivirus. If you don't want the small slowdown, are wise enough to spot obvious traps like fraudulent websites asking you to install programs, etc, and you feel the risk is small enough, then don't install it.

Comment: Thanks @Fiksdal How about the iPhone that using iOS?

Comment: On non-jailbroken iPhones, I'd say iOS is so sandboxed and resilient to viruses that there's really no need for antivirus. Each app runs inside an extremely protected, closed environment, and there really is no way for it to do damage. There isn't even a way for a third party to create antivirus for iOS, because it would have to be an app, and an app running inside a sandbox can't act as a systemwide antivirus. Apple has very stringent programs to keep the App Store free of malware. Don't worry about viruses on iOS. More details here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103400/153510

Comment: I see. I got no worry now =)